# Can I invoke OpenCL kernels one after another, on the same device buffers?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu, simd

Suppose I copy data to the device using `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, and suppose that data is a buffer of `RGB` values (`unsigned char`s). I want to first turn the image into grayscale, by operating only on the input buffer (for example by overwriting the `R` component), and then I want to resize the resulting image into an output buffer. I would then use `clEnqueueReadBuffer` to copy the output back into host memory.

Since I cannot write a single kernel with all the logic (because of the inherent unordered nature of OpenCL processing), I was thinking of using a sequence of: `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` - two `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`s - `clEnqueueReadBuffer`.

Is this approach correct? Where in the specification can I find more details on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all are on same command queue and command queue is an in-order type then it works.

In-order queues execute all commands in-order. Each command sees the results from the latest command before it.

Here:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueue.html

it says

> For example, if an application calls clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to
>   execute kernel A followed by a clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to execute
>   kernel B, the application can assume that kernel A finishes first and
>   then kernel B is executed. If the memory objects output by kernel A
>   are inputs to kernel B then kernel B will see the correct data in
>   memory objects produced by execution of kernel A. If the

---

Note: applying grey-scale after the re-size could be more efficient if you won't use the original greyscale and it is a down-scale instead of up-scale. Also you can do both in single kernel if only re-sized image is needed greyscaled. When re-size workitem picks some pixels for resulting pixel, you can apply greyscale on resulting pixel.

If you are going to use both greyscaled original image and greyscaled resized image, you can have two outputs(not altering original image) and have two command queues in parallel to finish whole job quicker(if kernel launch overhead is comparable to kernel execution overhead) but this would need a sync point for both queues and might become slower for very small images(one queue needs to see buffer copy from other queue and both must finish later to have two results). Two kernels from two queues can use same buffer for read-only without any problem.

Only pay attention to setting right arguments to kernels before enqueueing commands to queues (there is no guarantee that they don't start immediately)

You can have as many kernel executions as you need but setting arguments are not a queue operation so needs to be taken care of at the beginning.